# Render part of component in other component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular-components

I'm quite new to Angular, and I'm wonder if it's possible to render part of a component inside of another component, [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3FdV.png)

I my AppComponent I just have a single `router-outlet` Like this:

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then I have a layout component with the header and navigation component, like this:

```
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>

    <div class="main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

In my navgiation component I have a simple strucutre with a title, navgiation items and some action butons:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div *ngIf="title.length" class="navigation__title">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__menu">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                <a routerLink="{{menuItem.path}}">{{menuItem.title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__actions">
        <a *ngFor="let actionButton of actions" (click)="actionButton.path"
            class="btn btn--primary">{{actionButton.title}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to know if it's possible to to render the action buttons from the currently active component, so that I can bind click event from the current component to them:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="20%">Name</th>
            <th width="20%">Emailaddress</th>
            <th width="20%">Phone number</th>
            <th width="40%">Teams</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
            <td><a (click)="editEmployee(employee.id)">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</a></td>
            <td>{{employee.emailAddress}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.phoneNumber}}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Showing <b>{{employees.length}}</b> out of <b>{{employees.length}}</b> employees</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<!-- Render this button in the navgiation component -->
<a class="btn btn--primary" (click)="createEmployee()">Add new</a>
<!---------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: yes, just make sure they are part of the same module. and insert the component where you want. Hide what you don't want to show with an ngIf statement.

Comment: @DavidAguirre I don't think that would work, because I want to bind a click event (that is in the currently active component) to it.

Comment: it will work. There are several ways for components to interact with one another. if you are going from parent to child then look into viewchild. You reach into the child component to use any click events within the class.

Comment: Your picture is more than clear. But "**currently active component**" - could you please make it less ambiguous? Which component are you referring here? It would be more helpful if you could denote them as either NavigationComponent or MyComponent1.

Comment: @MichaelD Yes sorry, currently active component would be `MyComponent1`. I mean currently active in the context of the currently activiated route. The `NavigationComponent` and `HeaderComponent` are always part of the `AppLayoutComponent` and I update them through a service.

Comment: What about ng-content? Put it between the selector and it ends up where ng-content tag is located.

Comment: Url: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/